# How can I configure openvpn server without push default gateway?

Tags: openvpn, route

I need configure my openvpn server to provide some LAN resources, but I don't want route all traffic for my clients.

Here is my sample network description:
My LAN is 192.168.1.0/24. Openvpn network is 192.168.100.0/24.
I add `push route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0` in my server side configuration. I would like to allow my clients can access 192.168.1.0/24, but not other traffic.

How can I do this from server side configuration?
Is client side configuration the only way to do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply do not add the `redirect-gateway` in the client or server configuration and the default gateway will not be changed.

Comment: There is no `redirect-gateway` in server configuration. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: Did you check on the client side as well?  The option can be set on either side.  Watch your OpenVPN log on the client when the connection is being established.  You should see messages about the gateway being switched, and if the option was pushed from the server or not.

Comment: I use NetworkManager for convenience and get confusion. It works with new client side configuration and without NetworkManager. Thanks.

Comment: @Solomon There might be something like `push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"` in `server.conf`. (At least in Ubuntu's default setup.) Changing that to `push "def1 bypass-dhcp"` makes the server not push a default gateway to clients.

Answer (score 41):

This is a client setting.

For Linux clients, in NetworkManager: Edit Connections -> VPN -> (select the vpn configuration you would like to edit) -> Edit -> IPv4/IPv6 -> Routes -> Check the box that says "Use this connection only for resources on its network"

Comment: is there any way to make this the default in the configuration file?

Comment: It can also be a server setting. See @Zoredache's answer.

Answer (score 9):

Due to I have ipv4 and ipv6, if I don't want openvpn to set my default gw, I had to add the following lines at my client configuration, and I had to add manually the ipv6 routes:

```
pull-filter ignore "route-gateway"
route-nopull
```

If I don't want all the ipv4 traffic necessarily going through my openvpn interface, I had to add only the following line

```
pull-filter ignore "route-gateway"
```

The line above would make that my traffic to hosts supporting ipv4 and pv6 will be going through my openvpn connection, while my traffic to hosts with only ipv4 will be going through my wireless interface.

My original client configuration before playing was:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote ovpn.myserver.com 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
verb 3
```

Regards,

Answer (score 6):

`route-nopull` in the .ovpn file, or `--route-nopull` on the command line.

You'll then have to set up the routes yourself, of course.

Answer (score 3):

I found that removing

```
resolv-retry infinite
```

from my client.conf stops pushing default route from server.

Comment: Thanks. This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

(For clients)

`--pull-filter ignore "<the beginning of the command, which sets the route>"`

To get the exact command, which server pushes, you must:

- enable logging with `verb 7` either in the config, or via command
  line;
- wipe the log to see clearer, `echo >/var/log/<whatever you named it>.log`;
- start openvpn;
- in the log search for `route` or `gateway`;
- add the command in the line with `pull-filter ignore`.

The command may look like `redirect-gateway def1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `pull-filter ignore "route-gateway"` to you .ovpn file. Then, remember to set your custom routes.

Example:

```
...
pull-filter ignore "route-gateway"
route-method exe
route-delay 2
allow-pull-fqdn
route <some subnet IP> <subnet mask> <gateway IP>
route <other subnet IP> <subnet mask> <gateway IP>
...
```

**NOTE**:
It works when launching vpn connection from shell:

```
sudo openvpn --config /home/sfernandez/Documentos/config/sfernandez.ovpn
```

For work stations, if you are going to use .ovpn file for importing configuration to create a new connection:

```
sudo nmcli connection import file /path/to/your/file/vpn_config.ovpn type openvpn
```

Then, you'll need to set this option in your UI connection manager. Something like:

IPv4 Settings -> Routes -> [x] Use this connection only for resources on your network.